# VBA subscript out of range error

Tags: vba

Guys here is the code below, Its was working fine for the month of May 05/30/2015. But for some reason it is crashing and giving me subscript of of range error.

I may have changed some links , just trying to conceptually understand what the error is , then debug it. The code is an OLEDB connection and pulls data by month

can you guys take a look

I dont get a line that is causing the error but its the SOI call is when it happens . I am thinking its a connection issue so will try to delete the OLEDB connection and redo it

```
 Sub Update()

    'PCAP
    Call ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1("PCAP", "zzFS - PCAP- SCRF3", "Apollo", "DB_PEFS521", "TSCRLWSQLCLP162\PEFS02")

    'Capital Activity Rec
    Call ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1("INVESTRAN DATA", "zzCapital Activity by Position rec - SCRF3", "Apollo", "DB_PEFS521", "TSCRLWSQLCLP162\PEFS02")

    'SOI
    Call ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1("SOI from JPM investran", "zz_Schedule of Investments", "Apollo", "DB_PEFS521", "TSCRLWSQLCLP162\PEFS02")

    'TB
    Call ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1("Sheet2", "TB Summary_BS", "Apollo", "DB_PEFS521", "TSCRLWSQLCLP162\PEFS02")

    MsgBox ("All Investran data tabs have been refreshed.")
 End Sub





Sub ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1(spreadsheet As Variant, DriverName As String, RWFolder As String, dbName As String, ServerName As String)

    'Sheets(spreadsheet).Visible = True
    'Sheets(spreadsheet).Select
    'Sheets(spreadsheet).Range("A1").Select
    Set lstObj = Sheets(spreadsheet).ListObjects(1)
    Set queryTbl = lstObj.QueryTable
    queryTbl.Connection = "OLEDB;Provider=ftiRSOLEDB.RSOLEDBProvider;" _
                    & "Integrated Security=" & """" & """" _
                    & ";Location=" & dbName & ";User ID=" & """" & """" _
                    & ";Initial Catalog=" & dbName & ";Data Source=" & ServerName _
                    & ";Mode=Read;Persist Security Info=True;Extended Properties="

    mycurrentvalue = """" & dbName & """"
    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & "." & """" & RWFolder & """"
    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & "." & """" & DriverName & """"

    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & " " & """"

    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & "begin date=" & Format(Range("BeginDate"), "mm/dd/yyyy") & """"
    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & " " & """"

    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & "End Date=" & Format(Range("EndDate"), "mm/dd/yyyy") & """"
    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & " " & """"

    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & "GL Begin Date=" & Format(Range("BeginDate"), "mm/dd/yyyy") & """"
    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & " " & """"

    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & "GL End Date=" & Format(Range("EndDate"), "mm/dd/yyyy") & """"
    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & " " & """"

    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & "Legal Entity=" & Range("LEID") & """"
    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & " " & """"

    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & "GL Date=" & Format(Range("EndDate"), "mm/dd/yyyy") & """"

    mycurrentvalue = mycurrentvalue & " FLAGS[/SILENT]"
    Debug.Print mycurrentvalue

    queryTbl.CommandText = mycurrentvalue
    queryTbl.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: It's helpful if you tell us what line is triggering the error.

Comment: `subscript of range` usually means  there is something in the code that the code can't find, most of the time it is a worksheet, or workbook. Usually when you hit debug, a line of code will be highlighted.

Comment: *I dont get a line that is causing the error*. Yes, you do :) When the error message appears, enter "Debug" mode and it should highlight the offending line. If the error raises on a function call, you can use F8 to step line-by-line through the function and identify where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

See if this code helps. I cleaned it up a little bit I think you are having an error because you do not have QueryTable object on the sheet.Option Explicit

```
Sub Update()

'PCAP
    Call ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1(Sheets("PCAP"), "zzFS - PCAP- SCRF3", "Apollo", "DB_PEFS521", "TSCRLWSQLCLP162\PEFS02")

    'Capital Activity Rec
    Call ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1(Sheets("INVESTRAN DATA"), "zzCapital Activity by Position rec - SCRF3", "Apollo", "DB_PEFS521", "TSCRLWSQLCLP162\PEFS02")

    'SOI
    Call ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1(Sheets("SOI from JPM investran"), "zz_Schedule of Investments", "Apollo", "DB_PEFS521", "TSCRLWSQLCLP162\PEFS02")

    'TB
    Call ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1(Sheets("Sheet2"), "TB Summary_BS", "Apollo", "DB_PEFS521", "TSCRLWSQLCLP162\PEFS02")

    MsgBox ("All Investran data tabs have been refreshed.")
End Sub



Sub ReplaceConnectionandRefresh1(ByRef shTable As Worksheet, _
                                 ByVal strDriverName As String, _
                                 ByVal strRWFolder As String, _
                                 ByVal strDataBase As String, _
                                 ByVal strServerName As String)

    Dim oQueryTbl As QueryTable
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strCommand As String


    ' Make sure you have query rables on the sheet.
    If Not shTable.QueryTables.Count = 0 Then

        ' Prepare the connection string
        strConnection = "OLEDB;Provider=ftiRSOLEDB.RSOLEDBProvider;" _
                        & "Integrated Security=" & """" & """" _
                        & ";Location=" & strDataBase & ";User ID=" & """" & """" _
                        & ";Initial Catalog=" & strDataBase & ";Data Source=" & strServerName _
                        & ";Mode=Read;Persist Security Info=True;Extended Properties="

        ' Prepare the command
        strCommand = """" & strDataBase & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & "." & """" & strRWFolder & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & "." & """" & strDriverName & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & " " & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & "begin date=" & Format(Range("BeginDate").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & " " & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & "End Date=" & Format(Range("EndDate").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & " " & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & "GL Begin Date=" & Format(Range("BeginDate").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & " " & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & "GL End Date=" & Format(Range("EndDate").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & " " & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & "Legal Entity=" & Range("LEID").Value & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & " " & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & "GL Date=" & Format(Range("EndDate").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & """"
        strCommand = strCommand & " FLAGS[/SILENT]"

        Debug.Print strCommand

        ' Add the connection information and refresh.
        With shTable.QueryTables(1)
            .Connection = strConnection
            .CommandText = strCommand
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "There is not query tables in sheet " & shTable.Name, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps :)